# Swift playground shows wrong number of executions for statement (forEach on array)

Tags: swift, foreach, swift-playground

I've been exploring functors and I'm having a little trouble understanding what the `forEach` functor is doing behind the scenes. For example when I input this into a playground:

```
let array = [1] // [1]
array.forEach { $0.value } // (3 times)
array.forEach { _ in print("hello") } // (2 times)
```

When I expand the `(3 times)` or `(2 times)` it simply shows `()`

For one, why are there multiple executions on an array of 1 element, and why do the two `forEach` computations vary in number of executions?

Comment: `forEach()` calls the closure exactly once for each array element. If the Playground indicates something else then it is a bug in Playground. When in doubt, use a compiled project and add debug output or set breakpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a confusing situation.

Let's consider the second `forEach` first:

```
array.forEach { _ in print("hello") } // (2 times)
```

Different parts of that line are executed at different times, and Swift counts each of those times as a separate execution. The first time is when it calls `array.forEach`, and the second time is inside that call to `forEach` when it executes the call to `print` in the body of the anonymous function. If we put newlines in, we can see that Swift only executes each line once and reports its “value”:

```
array.forEach { _ in  // [1]
    print("hello")    // ()
}
```

We can also try putting the anonymous function in a variable:

```
let p: (Int) -> () = { _ in print("hello") } // (2 times)
array.forEach(p)                             // [1]
```

Above, Swift executes part of the `let p` line once to create the anonymous function and store it in `p`, and another part of the line later to call `print` inside the body of the function.

Swift reports that the value of the `print` line is `()` because `forEach`s argument must be a function that returns `()` (the empty tuple, aka `Void`). Since `print` already returns `()`, Swift just lets that be the value of the line.

Before we go back to consider your first `forEach` example, let's consider one other example:

```
print("hello"); print("goodbye") // (2 times)
```

Swift says this line executes two times because each individual statement on the line counts as a separate execution.

So now let's consider your first example:

```
array.forEach { $0.value } // (3 times)
```

Let's try it with newlines:

```
array.forEach {  // [1]
    $0.value     // (2 times)
}
```

OK, so the `forEach` call itself counts as one execution, as expected. But Swift claims it is executing the body of the anonymous function twice. Why?

Recall that `forEach`'s argument must be a function that returns `()`. But the type of `$0.value` is not `()`; it is the internal type `Builtin.Int64`. So Swift inserts another statement at the end of the line, to return `()`. Effectively, Swift acts like you wrote this:

```
array.forEach {    // [1]
    $0.value; ()   // (2 times)
}
```

And we can prove that by explicitly adding another line to the function:

```
array.forEach {  // [1]
    $0.value     // <<<opaque type>>>
    ()
}
```

Now Swift thinks each line is executed once, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What you see in right column of Swift playground is not number of executions of this particular row but the number of statements in this row giving some result that can be displayed in this column.

`array.forEach { $0.value }` gives `(3 times)` because it resolves to three results: first for `array`, second and third for `$0.value`.

Change this line to:

```
array.forEach { \\ [1]
    $0          \\ (2 times)
}
```

`$0` gives two result. First result is given by evaluating `$0` and second by evaluating implicit `return ()` statement. Let's make it explicit:

```
array.forEach {  // [1]
    $0           // 1
    return ()    // ()
}
```

When you expand `(N times)` result playground should show you results of all statements in this line, but it does this with bugs. Sometimes it shows all results or only last result or only first result or no results. I do not why.